# Is my example a run-on sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is my example a run-on?

> "Assuming I have a dog and my ex-wife has a cat, both picture1 and picture2 show: (1) I am allergic to cat, (2) my ex-wife hates my dog, and (3) we're not happy."

Edit: I changed the math equation to actual sentences since it was confusing people. Note that even though I am using small/simple sentences for (1), (2), (3), my original sentences for (1), (2), and (3) are quite long.

Comment: Are you missing the conclusion for (3)?   Maybe it would be clearer as:  Given e=5, k=12 and assuming a=1, ... both Table1 and Table2 show the same conclusions ...

Answer (score 1):

A run-on sentence, by definition, is: a sentence that is the result of two or more complete sentences (independent clauses) being joined without any punctuation; they are connected improperly. What is an independent clause, you ask? It's merely a phrase that when extracted from the original, larger sentence, is itself a 100% grammatically correct sentence.

Your example above is **not** a run-on sentence because you're employing all the proper and necessary punctuation to construct your sentence. You're adding commas, colons, and a full stop. If you omitted all the punctuation you have, then yes, in that case, your sentence would most definitely be a run-on sentence.

Comment: It might be helpful to point out that a sentence can be long and overly complicated, making it difficult to understand, but still not be a run-on. But I don't think the example sentence is too complex.

Comment: Here's a useful reference: http://writing.umn.edu/sws/assets/pdf/quicktips/run-ons.pdf

Comment: Also, something like "I woke up and I ate breakfast and I went to school and I ate lunch and I went home." is not technically a run-on, but it's still poorly constructed.